# creating a project

Tags: android

I am currently following the steps in the book "android app development for dummies", and I have reached the part where I need to create a new project. The problem I am having is that my window is different to the one in the book so I can not follow the steps in the book as my window is different.

My window says "android application project" and in the book it says "android project" and so when i click on it to proceed, my next window is different to the one in the book.

Does anyone know why this is? and how i may be able to fix it?

Comment: Use your fantasy to explore and try on your own...

Answer (score 3):

The SDK was changed, which means your book is outdated. I recommend using the official Android developer training instead here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it may be my version of eclipse that is different, because even the link you sent me is different from my screen? I am not quite sure what I should do?

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot?